# Problem with dismiss view controller when present view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have RootVC: UITableViewController, which contains a list of password. When I click on password they open in ViewPasswordVC. When i click "edit" password open in EditPasswordVC. When I click "cancel" or "save" in EditPasswordVC i back only one step back, but I want back to RootVC.
(VC = View Controller)

Here you can see my problem:

[image]

This is code when i click on password on RootVC in didSelectRowAt:

```
let viewPasswordVC = ViewPasswordVC()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewPasswordVC, animated: true)
```

This is code when I click "edit" in password:

```
let editPasswordVC = EditPasswordVC()
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: editPasswordVC)
self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And this is code when I click "cancel" when I'm in EditPasswordVC (same thing and when I click save):

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

How I can fix this? I want when I click "cancel" or "save" in EditPasswordVC, to get me back on RootVC, not to ViewPasswordVC.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually dismissing your current ViewController but previous ViewController isn't the first so you can't expect that you gets to the `RootVC`. You have to declare what should happen when you dismiss `EditPasswordVC`, to achieve this follow these steps:

First create delegate protocol for `EditPasswordVC`

```
protocol EditPasswordVCDelegate {
    func editDidEnd()
}
```

then in `EditPasswordVC` create variable for delegate

```
var delegate: EditPasswordVCDelegate?
```

next implement this protocol to `ViewPasswordVC`

```
class ViewPasswordVC: UIViewController, EditPasswordVCDelegate
```

then before you present `editPasswordVC` set its delegate as self

```
let editPasswordVC = EditPasswordVC()
editPasswordVC.delegate = self
```

Now in `ViewPasswordVC` declare that you want to go to the root when edit did end. So add `EditPasswordVCDelegate` delegate method

```
func editDidEnd() {
    navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Now declare what should happen when `EditPasswordVC` did disappear. You want to call method on delegate

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    delegate?.editDidEnd()
}
```

now you can call

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I put this code, it stays on the same view controller (EditPasswordVC).